# How to refresh a MS Access linked table (with Excel file) programatically via C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, jet, linked-tables

I am trying to automate a process and thus need to programatically refresh a linked table in MS Access via C#. My table is already linked to myExcelFile.xlsx in a folder ../data/daily_inputs/, I just need to refresh it.

I have googled for a solution but none have been helpful. What do I use.. Oledb, Linq, JET, maybe a special SQL query? If anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to refresh. Access will always read data from the current Excel file.